# (1/1) InvalidArgumentException Attribute [view] does not exist. Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

When I add the

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
```

on web.php, I've encountered this error.

(1/1) InvalidArgumentException

```
Attribute [view] does not exist.
in RouteRegistrar.php (line 75)
at RouteRegistrar->attribute('view', '/')in Router.php (line 1098)
at Router->__call('view', array('/', 'welcome'))in Facade.php (line 221)
at Facade::__callStatic('view', array('/', 'welcome'))in web.php (line 20)
at require('C:\\wamp64\\www\\crystalcode\\routes\\web.php')in Router.php (line 327)
at Router->loadRoutes('C:\\wamp64\\www\\crystalcode\\routes/web.php')in Router.php (line 283)
at Router->group(array('middleware' => 'web', 'namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers'), 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\crystalcode\\routes/web.php')in RouteRegistrar.php (line 104)
at RouteRegistrar->group('C:\\wamp64\\www\\crystalcode\\routes/web.php')in RouteServiceProvider.php (line 56)
at RouteServiceProvider->mapWebRoutes()in RouteServiceProvider.php (line 40)
at RouteServiceProvider->map()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map'), array())in BoundMethod.php (line 29)
at BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()in BoundMethod.php (line 87)
at BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(object(Application), array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map'), object(Closure))in BoundMethod.php (line 31)
at BoundMethod::call(object(Application), array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map'), array(), null)in Container.php (line 539)
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map'))in RouteServiceProvider.php (line 74)
at RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes()in RouteServiceProvider.php (line 33)
at RouteServiceProvider->boot()in RouteServiceProvider.php (line 28)
at RouteServiceProvider->boot()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'), array())in BoundMethod.php (line 29)
at BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()in BoundMethod.php (line 87)
at BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(object(Application), array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'), object(Closure))in BoundMethod.php (line 31)
at BoundMethod::call(object(Application), array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'), array(), null)in Container.php (line 539)
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'))in Application.php (line 788)
at Application->bootProvider(object(RouteServiceProvider))in Application.php (line 771)
at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(object(RouteServiceProvider), 17)
at array_walk(array(object(EventServiceProvider), object(LogServiceProvider), object(RoutingServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(CookieServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(EncryptionServiceProvider), object(FilesystemServiceProvider), object(FormRequestServiceProvider), object(FoundationServiceProvider), object(NotificationServiceProvider), object(PaginationServiceProvider), object(SessionServiceProvider), object(ViewServiceProvider), object(AppServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(EventServiceProvider), object(RouteServiceProvider)), object(Closure))in Application.php (line 772)
at Application->boot()in BootProviders.php (line 17)
at BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application))in Application.php (line 208)
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadEnvironmentVariables', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\BootProviders'))in Kernel.php (line 162)
at Kernel->bootstrap()in Kernel.php (line 146)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))in index.php (line 53)
```

How to fix this issue, I'm beginner for the laravel please help me to set up this properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature in Laravel 5.5 - it's a shortcut for calling the Route::get method with a callback that calls your view as @rafik describes.
You are probably using a previous version of Laravel, but are reading about the Route::view() shortcut in the 5.5 documents.  It would actually be helpful if Laravel put a note next to new features telling since what version the feature has been available (see CakePHP documentation, php, etc).

So you need to either update your app (composer update) to the newer version of Laravel, or use a standard Route method (get, post, etc.) and call the view in a function.

Answer (score 0):

The ROUTE works as follow :

```
Route::method('URL', 'Controller OR ControllerAction OR function');
//     ^^^^^^  ^^^               ^^^^^^
//        1     2                   3
```

- The method you want to use to access the `URL` (HTTP Method, ie.
  `POST`, `GET` etc... and a "special" method `resource`)
- The url you want (ie. `/home`, `'/'` etc...)
- If you specified the `resource` method, you need to provide the name
  of the controller you want to use that contains the `index`,
  `create`, `store`, `edit` `update`, `delete` methods (you can use
  `php artisan make:controller myController --resource`to automatically
  generate that kind of controllers. ie. `HomeController`, Laravel will
  automatically create for you all the route that links to these
  methods with the appropriate `HTTP` method.
- If you specify a normal `HTTP` method, you need to provide either a
  function that will be called when a user access that URL, or an
  Action (method in a controller) ie. `MyController@MyAction`.

In your example, to simply return a view when accessing a URL :

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('welcome');
});
```

The route facade accepts only a valid method (the way you access to the route -- `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE` -- and a `resource` (which means it will automatically the four methods and link it to your controller the you specify as second argument)

Comment: Thanks, It's great now i know how it's worked but laravel need to used  the file extension "welcome.blade.php"? to run my page?

Comment: Cause when I try to run my page using routes, I'm also having an error

Comment: (1/1) NotFoundHttpException

in RouteCollection.php (line 179)
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))in Router.php (line 546)

Comment: Your views must be placed in the resources/views directory. and named 'xxx.blade.php'. Accessing a view in a subdirectory of the views folder use the dot syntax : 'myfolder.myview'.